# get specific image size in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

i have been using following code to get all the featured images of the child pages and display then in carousel slider but i want specific size =231*130 and class= img-responsive.
But i am not able to do it

```
<?php
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => 67, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {    
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue; ?>                                     

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"> 
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID, array( 231, 130 ), array( 'class' => 'img-responsive img-shadow' ) ) ); ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            </a>    

            <div class="caption clearfix">
                <h4><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h4>
                <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>">view all</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `wp_get_attachment_image` ([CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image))

in your case:

```
<?php
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => 67, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {    
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue; ?>                                     

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"> 
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'child-page','', array('class'    => "img-responsive img-shadow", 'alt'   => get_the_title()))  ?>
                <?php echo $image; ?> 
            </a>    

            <div class="caption clearfix">
                <h4><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h4>
                <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>">view all</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

and in your functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'child-page', 231, 130, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up your arguments here:

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ,array(231,130),array('class'=>'img-responsive img-shadow') ));?>
```

`get_post_thumbnail_id` only takes a page id. Really though, you're nesting two function when one should do. Use this:

```
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(231,130), array('class' => 'img-responsive img-shadow')); ?>
```

This will also echo the results, so you can remove the second line. [Here's the Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) for that function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be help you:-

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(231,130), array('class' => 'img-responsive img-shadow'));?>
</a>
```

Comment: See My Updated Answer. You need to add `echo` for this function.

Comment: i tried it but its not giving the proper image size i want, thanks any ways, i have marked the correct answer above